# ¿Cómo agregar espacio a disco virtualbox?

Tags: linux

hola acabo de agregar espacio a un s.o virtual en virtualbox de 5.6G a 11GB , virtualbox lo reconoce, pero dentro , con fdisk me sale que a la partición que sda4 a la que el habia añadido 5 gb , en df no se refleja ,

```
DF:/dev/sda4 5.6GB
fdisk -l :/dev/sda4 10.6GB
```

¿Alguna solución? Porque al parecer no se ha agregado el espacio a la particion porque al tratar de instalar algo me sale que el disco esta lleno.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta pregunta no versa sobre programación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Probaste a hacerle un resize2fs?

```
resize2fs /dev/sda4
```

¿Como hiciste la ampliación?
Yo tuve que ampliar el disco duro virtual de una VM hace poco, y tuve que hacerlo desde la consola con

```
VBoxManage modifyhd <ruta absoluta HDD virt> --resize <tamaño final en MB>
```

Pero después tuve que entrar en el SO guest aparecía como espacio sin particionar, y tuve que añadirlo a la partición con gparted.

[Más información sobre modifyhd](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi) en la documentación online de VirtualBox.

Comment: Hice lo mismo con vboxmanage para ampliar el tamaño del disco , y luego use fdisk para ampliar dentro del sistema,pero usando df , no lo reconoce.

Answer (score 1):

Esto va a depender de como hayas hecho la gestión del disco en el sistema virtualizado.
Si usaste [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) para particionar el disco, podrias mirar la documentación de como hacerlo (no tengo de memoria el comando). Basicamente lo que haces con este sistema de gestión de particiones, es ir agregando volumenes de datos, independiente de donde estén estos al FS.